# Sync and Send trait when using rayon parallel iterators

Tags: rust, iterator, synchronization

I have a collection of my trait, and I'd like to be able to call a mutable method of the trait for each of the items in my map.

At the moment I do this sequentially and my collection looks like the following:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::*;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Trait {
    fn foo_mut(&mut self);
}

fn main() {
    let mut items: HashMap<i32, Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>> = HashMap::new();
    // I have a separate data structure that holds Week<RefCell<dyn Trait>>

    for item in items.values_mut() {
        item.borrow_mut().foo_mut();
    }
}
```

I'd like to call the trait method in parallel now, so I  first changed my data structure to:

```rust
use std::collections::*;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};

fn main() {
    let mut items: HashMap<i32, Arc<RwLock<dyn Trait>>> = HashMap::new();

    for item in items.values_mut() {
        item.write().unwrap().foo_mut();
    }
}
```

then I came across [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.3.0/rayon/index.html), and I tried to use its parallel iterators, but the following code raises an error:

```rust
items.par_iter_mut().for_each(|(id, item)| item.write().unwrap().foo_mut());
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `par_iter_mut` found for struct `std::collections::HashMap<i32, std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<dyn Trait>>>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:12:11
    |
12  |       items.par_iter_mut().for_each(|(id, item)| item.write().unwrap().foo_mut());
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: there is an associated function with a similar name: `iter_mut`
    |
    = note: the method `par_iter_mut` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut std::collections::HashMap<i32, std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<dyn Trait>>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
            which is required by `std::collections::HashMap<i32, std::sync::Arc<std::sync::RwLock<dyn Trait>>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelRefMutIterator`
```

I checked the [for_each](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.3.0/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.for_each) documentation, and it requires `Self::Item` to be `Send` and the closure to be `Send + Sync`, now from what I can see [Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) is already `Send + Sync`, but the code can be fixed by adding both these traits to mine like:

```rust
let mut items: HashMap<i32, Arc<RwLock<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>>> = HashMap::new();
```

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementations of `Send` and `Sync` for `Arc<T>` look like [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#implementations):

```
impl<T> Send for Arc<T>
where
    T: Send + Sync + ?Sized, 

impl<T> Sync for Arc<T>
where
    T: Send + Sync + ?Sized,
```

This means that `Arc<T>` is only `Send` and `Sync` if `T` is too (See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#thread-safety)
for an explanation of why).

Likewise, `RwLock<T>` is only `Send` and `Sync` if `T` [is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#implementations):

```
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Send for RwLock<T>
impl<T: ?Sized + Send + Sync> Sync for RwLock<T>
```

Together, this means that `Arc<RwLock<dyn Trait>>` will only be `Send` and `Sync` if `dyn Trait` is too. If it is cumbersome to write `dyn Trait + Send + Sync` and you know that you never want to implement `Trait` for any types aren't `Send` or `Sync`, then you can add these as bounds to the trait:

```
trait Trait: Send + Sync {
    fn foo_mut(&mut self);
}
```

Then your original code with `Arc<RwLock<dyn Trait>>` will work with `rayon`.